# Add id or class to jqm listview data-filter generated text input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to use a function to clear the text box in a jqm listview data-filter input. I'm using JQM 1.3.2 so can't use the filterable widget which it seems would have solved this.

```
<ul id="external" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search all cards..." data-inset="true">
```

I feel like I should be able to use:

```
$('#external').val("");
```

But it does nothing.

Am I right to target the id of the UL containing the search field? Or is there a way to assign an id to the "listview data-filter" generated text field?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this bit of code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#clear-filter', function(){       
        $('input[data-type="search"]').val('');
        $('input[data-type="search"]').trigger("keyup");
    });
</script>

<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">    
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li><a href=#>Cat</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Dog</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Mouse</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">       
       <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear-filter"/>
    </div>
</div>
```